# Not see syntax error, was working at JSfiddle

Tags: vue.js

It is a simplifyed fork from a tiny demo,  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/commits.html
and is running (!)  at https://jsfiddle.net/gj1bryna/

The `<li>`  block was simplified to

```
<li v-for="record in xx">
  <a :href="record.html_url" target="_blank" class="commit">{{ record.sha }}</a>
</li>
```

An at code renamed `commits` to `xx`  and removed filters.

But when join all in one page... **It is not working at *this temporary page***  (was temporary, now editing to show difference)

When load the console show "ReferenceError: xx is not defined" eror.

---

EDIT

The difference was here:

```
  data: {
    branches: ['oficial.ls', 'oficial.ls_summary'],
    currentBranch: 'oficial.ls_summary',
    commits: null
  },
```

(I not renamed `commits` to `xx`  here, **sorry**)

PS: it is a typical case where error message is not so abvious about real problem... And beacuse programmer is imagining a sequence (where initialization exists) and real execution is other sequence.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gj1bryna/3/

Comment: So, why `-1`??  Please say or not vote

Comment: It wasn't me ..

Comment: Sorry @samayo, and thanks by tour solution (!), was the first to see the initialization problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So? xx is `undefined`. Why did you replaced `commits`?

If you really want to have different name, then rename the property from data option as well:

```
//So, you should have
data() {
  return {
    xx: [] // commits renamed or say xx is initialized
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, Vue won't be able to fine `#demo` since it's trying to mount it before it exists.

Comment: Thank, was a fast answer (!).  @samayo also offer solution with data `xx: ''`... So was an initialization problem. I not understand why it works at JSfiddle but not at real page.